# Problems with a navigation bar using CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css, frontend

I'm currently a beginner, and I need some help.

My site is supposed to look like this:

Navigation bar in color gray, transparent with white text. When you are in that page the button turns yellow

[image: expected site]

But it looks like this:

A big white space above the bar. It's JUST on that page "Equipo". The buttons do not turn yellow when clicked, and the text is black

[image: actual site]

If I could get some help on the highlighted text (which is in a BIG yellow box for some reason) that would be awesome too!

**The CSS for the navbar**

```
<style>@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway&display=swap');
</style>
/* General __________________________*/

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


/*Navbar________________________*/

.menu {
    top: 0;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.3);
    position: fixed;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 16px;
    padding-bottom: 16px;
    padding-left: 22px;
    padding-right: 22px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    letter-spacing: 1pt;
}

a:active {
    background-color: #FFCC00;
}

a:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
```

**This is the HTML for that page.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Equipo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css">
</head>

<body>
<!--Menú-->
<li><a href="#equipo">Equipo</a></li>
<ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Inicio</a></li>
        <li><a href="medio.html">Medio</a></li>
        <li><a href="equipo.html">Equipo</a></li>
        <li><a href="contacto.html">Contacto</a></li>
</ul>

<!--Banner-->
<div class="col-12 banner" id="bannerequipo">
</div>

<!--Cajas-->
<div class="container">
<div class="estante">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
        <div class="caja">
            <h1>Defendamos juntos el medio ambiente</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
        <div class="caja">
            <h3>Programas</h3>
            <img src="img/logo_onu.png" alt="Logo de la ONU">

            <p>El <a href="https://www.unenvironment.org/es">Programa de las Naciones Unidas para el Medio Ambiente</a> es el portavoz, dentro del sistema de la ONU, para la coordinación de actividades y toma de iniciativas de conciencia global.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
        <div class="caja">
            <h3>Activistas</h3>
            <img src="img/logo_greenpeace.png" alt="Logo de Greenpeace">
            <p>La ONG <a href="https://www.greenpeace.org/argentina/"> Greenpeace</a> es un ejemplo de movimiento que defiende el medio ambiente, y está integrado por más de 3 millones de personas en 55 países que actúan para poner fin a los atentados del humano contra la naturaleza.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
        <div class="caja">
            <h3>Voluntarios</h3>
            <p>En Latinoamérica existen diversas iniciativas que nuclean a la población preocupada por el impacto medioambiental que tienen las decisiones políticas, y a técnicos especializados en el medio ambiente, entre las cuales destacamos:</p>
<!--links-->
            <a href="http://laredvida.org">Red Vida (Lat)</a><br>
            <a href="http://www.movusuruguay.org">Movus (Uy)</a><br>
            <a href="http://gudynas.com">Gudynas.com (Uy)</a><br>
            <a href="http://porelagua.sejuntalagente.org">Asamblea por el agua (Uy)</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<!--Footer-->
        <div class="col-12" id="footer"><img src="img/logo.png">
            <h4>Lic. en Diseño de Comunicación Visual</h4>
            <h5>FADU | UDELAR</h5>
        </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please share your markup and CSS styles so there is more information to go on? It is most likely something in your CSS that is causing the issue.

Edit:  Thanks for sharing the code.  The reason why your anchors are turning yellow is because you've set their background-color to yellow when they're active.  Refer to the following:  https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_active.asp

Also, I recommend learning how to use Chrome's devtools to inspect your markup and styles so you can more easily see how your layout is broken.  Refer here: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools

Comment: Suggestion, if you are not answering question maybe it's better to add a comment rather than put it in the answer

Comment: Sorry, couldn't add a comment due to not having enough rep *shrug*

Comment: Ah didn't know that, sorry!